# Moving window of same application to different ubuntu workspace

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I'd like to find out how to move one Chrome window to another workspace. So far I've seen links that talk about moving different applications to different workspaces.

Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mouse**: Click "Activities" then drag the window to another workspace.

**Keyboard**: With the window active, press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, then hit <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to move the window to the next worksspace. Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> (left/right from Ubuntu 21.10 onwards) will work the same. When you do *not* hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>, these keybindings bring you to the next/previous workspace *without* moving the current window.

Comment: this was helpful, thank you!